# Lasalle's invariance principle for global stability of synchronization state of Kuramoto model

Tags: stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

**question**

My question regarding the argument of the proof of [theorem 3.1 in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.11410.pdf).

In the proof the Lasalle's invariance principle is used. From what I learned, radially unboundedness must hold for $V$ in order for global stability. However in the proof, I did not see whether and why radially unboundedness of $V(\vec\theta):=-\sum a_{ij}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)$ hold. It seems obvious that $-\sum a_{ij}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)$ is not radially unbounded (Take $\vec\theta=(\theta_0,\cdots,\theta_0)$ and $\theta_0 \rightarrow \infty$, then $-\sum a_{ij}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)=\sum a_{ij}$ which does not goes to infinity).

If it is indeed not radially unbounded, then how does the global stability obtained in the paper? Is it because *The system being defined on a compact manifold $\mathbb{T}^n$* stated in the proof?

Could someone help? Many thanks in advance!